# Eclipse + PyDev debug message: [Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console

Tags: eclipse, pydev

So I'm trying to debug. 
How exactly in debug view to connect the frame ? 
I looked in debug view, tried to do something in stacks nothing helps. There seems to be no option to connect. Under PyDev option in popup menu in debug stack frame I have option 2to3 and code analyses nothing about connection or console.

```
asdrew
[Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console.
4321
[Invalid Frame]: Please select frame to connect the console.
```

Comment: Can you explain under which scenario are you trying to debug (i.e.: interactive console, run a module in debug mode, remote debugger)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think there was an issue with different versions of my programs. Initially I had java files + eclipse x64 installed with python x86. 
I've made it all work this way: java 8 x86 + eclipse x86+ python x86 installed on my computer.